# In python i can not give a value in loo cross validation except zero as using svm.How can i fix it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, cross-validation

> When i try with 5 fold or 10 fold cv,results are normal but when i try
>   leave one out cross validation,it gives me zero values all times.

```
features_list=((features_array[0])[0])
labels_list= ((labels_array[0][0]))
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10,random_state=None,shuffle=True)
loo=model_selection.LeaveOneOut()
predictions = model_selection.cross_val_predict(SVC(),features_list,labels_list,cv=loo)
print(predictions)
accuracy=metrics.accuracy_score(labels_list,predictions)
```

Comment: Have you tried instantiating `SVC` outside of the cross-val predict? I haven't seen someone do that, maybe it's the source of your problem?

Comment: ` svc = SVC()
svc1=svc.fit(features_list,labels_list)
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10,random_state=None,shuffle=True)
loo=model_selection.LeaveOneOut()
predictions = model_selection.cross_val_predict(svc1,features_list,labels_list,cv=loo)` this is also not working if you mean this unfortunately.

Comment: I mean after `loo=...`, write `svm = SVC()` then in `cross_val_predict` replace `SVC()` for `svm`. It's just a wild guess though

Comment: It did not work as well,there is no problem when i use kfold cv,so weird.